# JS способ, который будет брать в Focus input во всплывающем окне

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

Помогите, пожалуйста, с темой focus();

Есть input, который появляется в следствии нажатия на элемент.
Как сделать, чтобы после нажатия на элемент, выпадающий input выбирался в focus?

Ниже приведу пример кода.

Есть пример кода на JQuery, нужен аналог на JS Native.

Вот это код на JQuery, он активирует выпадающее окно и берёт в focus.

```
$('.search').click(function() {
 $('.search-field').slideToggle();
 $('.search-field input[type=text]').focus();
});
```

```
Это мой код, который делает то же самое, но не знаю, как добавить, чтобы брал в focus.
```

```
let search = document.querySelector('.search');
let sF = document.querySelector('.search-field');



search.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (sF.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
        sF.style.visibility = 'visible';
        sF.style.opacity = '100%';
        myInput.focus();
    } else {
        sF.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        sF.style.opacity = '0%';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть метод **[focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)**, который можно применить на элементе, чтобы навести фокус

Comment: Да, я это знаю, но в данном контексте я не смог найти, как его записать (вопрос в синтаксисе).

Comment: Не ясно........ Элемент.focus() ....... Даже непонятно что тут ещё писать если прямо открыто написано.

Comment: Так вон же в коде есть эта строчка, но не работает xD

Comment: ну да, myInput из воздуха взялся, чего бы ему работать?

Comment: Алексей, строчка не работала, потому что нужно сначала было дождаться того, чтобы выплыло окно. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, я нашёл ответ на свой вопрос.

Недостаточно было прописать только `focus()` по той причине, что `focus()` не срабатывал из-за `transition-duration 300ms`.

Логично предположить, что если накидаем задачи, они выполнятся по очереди и сразу, и никто не будет ждать, когда окно выплывет.

Т.е. `focus()` пытается примениться для ещё неоткрытого окна.

Далее, можно решить вопрос асинхронным подходом.
Вешаем `setTimeout()`, ждём, когда выплывет окно, и только потом вешается `focus()`.

```js
const search = document.querySelector('.search');
const sF = document.querySelector('.search-field');
const input = sF.querySelector('.inputM');




search.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (sF.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
    sF.style.visibility = 'visible';
    sF.style.opacity = '100%';
    setTimeout(() => {
      return input.focus();
    }, 100);
  } else {
    sF.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    sF.style.opacity = '0%';
  }
});
```